# Min Coin Change Top Down Approach

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I tried to solve the minimum of coins change problem on Leetcode but only passing for some tests. I used Java language and my approach is the dynamic top-down approach. I know the problem could be related to some cases that the amount can't be calculated to the given coin changes, but not sure how to fix it. Thanks, guys!

This is the problem

```
You are given an integer array of coins representing coins of different denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of money.

Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.

You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.

Example 1:

Input: coins = [1,2,5], amount = 11
Output: 3
Explanation: 11 = 5 + 5 + 1
```

This is my solution

```
    public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        if (amount == 0)
            return 0;
        int [] dp = new int[amount + 1];
        Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int start = 0;
        int res = helper(coins, dp, amount, start);
        if(res == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            return -1;
        return res;
    }
    
    public int helper(int[]coins, int [] dp, int amount, int start ){
        if(amount == 0)
            return 0;
        if(dp[amount] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            return dp[amount];
        for (int i = start; i < coins.length; ++i){
            if(coins[i] <= amount){
                int coinToTakeAtThatAmount = helper(coins, dp, amount - coins[i], i) + 1;
                dp[amount] = Math.min(dp[amount],  coinToTakeAtThatAmount );
            }          
        }

        return dp[amount];
    }
```

Comment: Try `coins = [2,3]` with `amount = 3`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` is a negative value. As `helper` can return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you should not add 1 to it. One solution is to evaluate `1 + Math.min(dp[amount] - 1, helper(.....))`.
- The `dp` array will sometimes get values that were found when `start` was greater than 0. This means it represents a solution when you have fewer coins available. Yet, when getting out of several recursion levels, there may be a new call where `start` is less and thus allowing *more* coins, and yet the `if(dp[amount] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)` will choose a solution that may not be optimal when you have more coins available.

One idea to solve the second point could be to maintain a 2-dimensional array for `dp`, where also the value of `start` is used for a dimension, but this will not be efficient enough.

A better idea is to fill the 1-D `dp` array for all amounts based on *one* coin only, and then find improvements by using a second coin,...etc. This can actually be done through iteration without recursion.

So a working solution would be:

```java
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    int[] dp = new int[amount + 1];
    Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    // Base case: the number of coins needed for getting 0 is 0.
    dp[0] = 0;
    // Consider one coin at a time: 
    for (int coin : coins) {
        // Find improvements for each individual amount, making use of this coin
        for (int target = coin; target <= amount; target++) {
            // See if using this coin is an improvement. Avoid adding to MAX_VALUE
            dp[target] = 1 + Math.min(dp[target] - 1, dp[target - coin]);
        }
    }
    return dp[amount] != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? dp[amount] : -1;
}
```

Comment: A note regarding readability -- `1 + Math.min(dp[target] - 1, dp[target - coin])` seems more confusing to me than `Math.min(dp[target], 1 + dp[target - coin])`. (The latter is also less code.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן, there was a reason for this change, which I mentioned in the first bullet point of my answer. These two are not equivalent when `dp[target - coin]` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks for clarifying -- I didn't read the whole answer.